# How to create a column marking if values are present in other columns in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have 5 columns of 5 different p-values. I am looking to mark in a new column when values in any of the 5 columns are present.

My data looks like this:

```
Gene   pvalue_group1 pvalue_group2 pvalue_group3 pvalue_group4 pvalue_group5
Gene1     0.01           0.2             NA           NA            NA
Gene2      NA            0.001           NA           NA            NA
Gene3     0.05           0.7             0.09         0.2           0.001
```

I am looking to output a column that would look like this:

```
Gene   pvalue_group1 pvalue_group2 pvalue_group3 pvalue_group4 pvalue_group5 Group
Gene1     0.01           0.2             NA           NA            NA       Group1, Group2
Gene2      NA            0.001           NA           NA            NA       Group2
Gene3     0.05           0.7             0.09         0.2           0.001    Group1, Group2, Group3, Group4, Group5
```

I've tried to create code based off similar questions, trying to use dplyr and mutate() but I haven't gotten very far, any help on what other functions I could try would be appreciated.

Example input data:

```
df <- structure(list(Gene = c("Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene3"), pvalue_group1 = c(0.01, 
NA, 0.05), pvalue_group2 = c(0.2, 0.001, 0.7), pvalue_group3 = c(NA, 
NA, 0.09), pvalue_group4 = c(NA, NA, 0.2), pvalue_group5 = c(NA, 
NA, 0.001)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)

x <- names(df)[-1]

df[, test := apply( .SD, 1, \(i) paste(x[which(!is.na(i))], collapse=',') ), .SDcols=x]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(-1) %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  select(-value) %>%
  group_by(Gene) %>%
  summarise(Group = list(name)) %>%
  select(Group) %>%
  bind_cols(df) %>%
  relocate(Group, .after = "pvalue_group5")

# # A tibble: 3 × 7
#   Gene  pvalue_group1 pvalue_group2 pvalue_group3 pvalue_group4 pvalue_group5 Group    
#   <chr>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl> <list>   
# 1 Gene1          0.01         0.2           NA             NA          NA     <chr [2]>
# 2 Gene2         NA            0.001         NA             NA          NA     <chr [1]>
# 3 Gene3          0.05         0.7            0.09           0.2         0.001 <chr [5]>
```

Alternatively, you could replace the `summarise` step with `summarise(Group = paste(name, collapse = ", "))` for a string-like output:

```r
df %>%
  pivot_longer(-1) %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  select(-value) %>%
  group_by(Gene) %>%
  summarise(Group = paste(name, collapse = ", ")) %>%
  select(Group) %>%
  bind_cols(df) %>%
  relocate(Group, .after = "pvalue_group5")

# # A tibble: 3 × 7
#   Gene  pvalue_group1 pvalue_group2 pvalue_group3 pvalue_group4 pvalue_group5 Group                                                                  
#   <chr>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl> <chr>                                                                  
# 1 Gene1          0.01         0.2           NA             NA          NA     pvalue_group1, pvalue_group2                                           
# 2 Gene2         NA            0.001         NA             NA          NA     pvalue_group2                                                          
# 3 Gene3          0.05         0.7            0.09           0.2         0.001 pvalue_group1, pvalue_group2, pvalue_group3, pvalue_group4, pvalue_gro…
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option:
Main feature is to use `cur_column()`. We check if across the columns the value is not NA, If so then put in column name .. and so on:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(-1, ~case_when(!is.na(.) ~ cur_column()), .names = 'new_{col}')) %>%
  unite(Group, starts_with('new'), na.rm = TRUE, sep = ' ') %>% 
  mutate(Group = str_replace_all(Group, 'pvalue_', ''))
```

```
   Gene pvalue_group1 pvalue_group2 pvalue_group3 pvalue_group4 pvalue_group5                              Group
1 Gene1          0.01         0.200            NA            NA            NA                      group1 group2
2 Gene2            NA         0.001            NA            NA            NA                             group2
3 Gene3          0.05         0.700          0.09           0.2         0.001 group1 group2 group3 group4 group5
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)
  
df %>% 
  mutate(pmap_dfr(.[,-1], ~ list(Group = names(df[,-1])[!is.na(c(...))] %>% 
    str_remove_all("pvalue_") %>% str_c(collapse = ", "))))

#>    Gene pvalue_group1 pvalue_group2 pvalue_group3 pvalue_group4 pvalue_group5
#> 1 Gene1          0.01         0.200            NA            NA            NA
#> 2 Gene2            NA         0.001            NA            NA            NA
#> 3 Gene3          0.05         0.700          0.09           0.2         0.001
#>                                    Group
#> 1                         group1, group2
#> 2                                 group2
#> 3 group1, group2, group3, group4, group5
```

---

Yet another possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Group = str_c(names(df[-1])[!is.na(c_across(-Gene))], collapse=", ") %>% 
    str_remove_all("pvalue_")) %>%
  ungroup
```

Output:

```
  Gene  pvalue_group1 pvalue_group2 pvalue_group3 pvalue_group4 pvalue_group5 Group                                 
  <chr>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl> <chr>                                 
1 Gene1          0.01         0.2           NA             NA          NA     group1, group2                        
2 Gene2         NA            0.001         NA             NA          NA     group2                                
3 Gene3          0.05         0.7            0.09           0.2         0.001 group1, group2, group3, group4, group5
```